# Angular2 (typescript) - can't load ng2-restangular

Tags: rest, angular, typescript

I actually struggle to load ng2-restangular (from https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ng2-restangular) in a new project.

Here is my config:

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        map: {
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
            'ng2-restangular': 'npm:ng2-restangular/dist/umd/ng2-restangular.js',
            'lodash':'npm:lodash'
        },
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            lodash: {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RestangularModule } from 'ng2-restangular';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        // Importing RestangularModule and making default configs for restanglar   
        RestangularModule.forRoot((RestangularProvider) => {
            RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://0.0.0.0:3011/api/');
//            RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
//                id: "_id"
//            });
        }
        )
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And app.component.ts:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Restangular } from 'ng2-restangular';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        template: '<h1>hello world</h1>'
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

        // If I remove this line...
        constructor(private restangular: Restangular) {
        }

        ngOnInit(): void {
//...and this one, everything works fine.   
 this.restangular.all('Annotations').getList().toPromise().then(function(annotations) {
                console.log(annotations);
            });
        }

        ngAfterViewInit(): void {

        }

    }
```

When I add the constructor I got this error:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property "rejection"
```

in
zone.js (ligne 386, col. 13)

Any idea?

Comment: Is restangular loading a script from a different origin? What are you accessing through the api?

Comment: it seems like all scripts are correctly loading from my localhost.
Example of datas i want to access : [{"kml":"test","id":"583467e59b7c51b60b83beeb"}] .
It was OK with angular and restangular 1.

Comment: But do you load any scripts with restangular? Do you use the same port for your angular app as for the restangular api?

Comment: No i'm not. My angular2 app is running on port 3000, and my API is hosted by loopbackjs on port 3011.

Comment: Still not sure if you answered my "do you load any scripts with restangular". :) Anyways, if you do, that is your problem. Angular2 uses `zone.js`, and this library does not allow accessing a script from another origin.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting what you mean. Could you provide any example of how I can a load script with restangular please?

Comment: Never mind. I didn't really look into restangular. I just know that that specific error from `zone.js` has to do with accessing scripts inside zone from a different origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I had to import HttpModule in app.module.ts
ex:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RestangularModule } from 'ng2-restangular';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        // Importing RestangularModule and making default configs for restanglar   
        RestangularModule.forRoot((RestangularProvider) => {
            RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://0.0.0.0:3011/api/');
        }
        )
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and use the typescript compiler in systemjs.config.js:

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        //use typescript for compilation
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        //typescript compiler options
        typescriptOptions: {
            emitDecoratorMetadata: true
        },
        paths: {
            'npm:': 'node_modules/',
            'ng2-restangular': 'node_modules/ng2-restangular/dist/esm/src'
        },
        map: {
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
            'typescript': 'npm:typescript/lib/typescript.js',
            'ng2-restangular': 'ng2-restangular',
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'lodash': 'npm:lodash'
        },
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.ts',
                defaultExtension: 'ts'
            },
            rxjs: {
                main: "./Rx.js",
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            lodash: {
                main: './lodash.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'ng2-restangular': {
                main: './index',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```